# How to update dependant combo in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have two combos and the second combo depends on the first combo. So options of the second combo should be reloaded when option is selected from the first combo. But how can **ng-model** of the second combo listen to the change of the **ng-model** of the first combo and update the options list in Angular 2?

Comment: NgModel directive has a event ng-model-change, you can attach handler to that https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgModel-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

One way is to attach a `(change)` event handler to the first combo:

```
template: `
  <select [(ngModel)]="c1Selection" #c1 (change)="onChange(c1.value)">
    <option *ngFor="#v of combo1">{{v}}</option>
  </select>
  <select [(ngModel)]="c2Selection">
    <option *ngFor="#v of combo2">{{v}}</option>
  </select>
`

class App {
  combo1 = 'one two three'.split(' ');
  combo2Map = {
    one:   '1 11 111'.split(' '),
    two:   '2 22 222'.split(' '),
    three: '3 33 333'.split(' ')
  };
  c1Selection = 'one';
  c2Selection = '';
  combo2 = this.combo2Map[this.c1Selection];
  constructor() {}
  onChange(c1Value) {
    this.combo2 = this.combo2Map[c1Value];
    this.c2Selection = '';
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JHsrai7JKRCeBsZKWUql?p=preview)</kbd>